# C program that can receive shutdown/terminate requests from linux/upstart/ubuntu

Tags: c, linux, shutdown, terminate

I have a coded a program in C for linux. At the moment I am using ubuntu upstart to run as a background service.

I want to be able to have the program gracefully shutdown when commanded instead of just being killed off. Can someone please point me to the functions used to receive such a command?

(edit: can't answer own post but it seems I am meant to use signal.h signal function to put callbacks on `SIGTERM` and `SIGKILL`).

Comment: You can't catch `SIGKILL`. Your program will always be forcibly terminated no matter what.

Comment: For most implementations of `init`, the procedure is to first signal all processes with SIGTERM, then follow up with SIGKILL to any process that doesn't exit within a short amount of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use [`sigaction(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sigaction) to define a handler to be run when `SIGTERM` is caught.